# Plymouth Interrupted during boot

Tags: boot, plymouth, systemd

I have installed a plymouth theme on my machine (Ubuntu Gnome 15.04) and before an update to systemd, everything worked. Now even with the kernel parameters as such:

```
quiet loglevel=3 rd.udev.log-priority=3 vga=current apparmor=1 security=apparmor systemd.show_status=0 splash
```

Plymouth gets interrupted by the version string message coming from systemd:

```
Starting version 219
```

And then it resumes, but frozen and messed up after the version string goes away. From all the reading I have done, it appears to be something wrong with systemd, as it's not listening to the "quiet" or the "rd.udev.log-priority=3 " kernel parameters.

Anyone have any ideas of how to get it to stop printing these messages and interrupting plymouth?

Comment: systemd?  Is this Vivid Vervet?

Comment: Yes it is Vivid Vervet.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Vivid Verver is currently off-topic here as well. However, on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs there are a bunch of developers waiting for bug reports and you helping them close bugs, so you might be better off there.  ;-)